# How to create SQLite trigger based on existence of value in table?

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I want to create a SQLite [trigger](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/) that will allow me to set the value of a particular property of a row based on the presence or absence of a value in already existing rows. Basically I want an auto incrementation of an integer value (let's say `count`) for a set of rows that all have the same string value for a particular property (let's say `name`). However, I want every `insert` into the table that holds these rows to check if the value for the row about to be inserted's `name` is already in the table or not. If it is, continue with the auto incrementation from the last row's (with the same `name`) `count`. If it does not, start a new auto increment of `count` for that group. I am new to SQLite but know the general basics. I can create the table:

```
create table exampleTable(name string, count integer)
```

I would want an example output (after successive entries of different `name`s) to look like this:

```
name|count
alek|1
alek|2
kevin|1
blaise|1
alek|3
kevin|2
alek|4
```

Now I know I can set `count` to auto increment by just defining it as the `primary key`, but then it would always just continue to count up by 1 upon every `insert`  regardless of the `name` value. I believe to do this I need to somehow get the trigger to check previous values so I know the trigger must utilize `before insert`. This is as much as I know, though. I do not know how to set up, basically, an if/else-type logic on how to restart an auto increment, nor do I know even how to *check* all/any of the tables previous rows' values of `name` as a basis for the if/else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trigger cannot change the values to be inserted; the only way to change the `count` value is to UDPATE it afterwards, i.e., in an AFTER INSERT trigger.

In general, the easiest way to use if/else logic with triggers is to use WHEN clauses:

```
CREATE TRIGGER count_same_name
AFTER INSERT ON exampleTable
WHEN NEW.count IS NULL
 AND (SELECT count(*)
      FROM exampleTable
      WHERE name = NEW.name
     ) > 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE exampleTable
    SET count = (SELECT MAX(count)
                 FROM exampleTable
                 WHERE name = NEW.name
                ) + 1
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;  -- or whatever the primary key is
END;

CREATE TRIGGER count_new_name
AFTER INSERT ON exampleTable
WHEN NEW.count IS NULL
 AND (SELECT count(*)
      FROM exampleTable
      WHERE name = NEW.name
     ) = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE exampleTable
    SET count = 1
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

But in this case, looking up the maximum value would return NULL if no value exists in the table, so you can simply use a single trigger with [ifnull()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull):

```
CREATE TRIGGER exampleTable_count
AFTER INSERT ON exampleTable
WHEN NEW.count IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE exampleTable
    SET count = ifnull((SELECT MAX(count)
                        FROM exampleTable
                        WHERE name = NEW.name
                       ), 0) + 1
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```